# help to claim erc20 every once in a while

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, transactions, remix

i want to create erc20 ex .. a

1. Total supply: 100,000 tokenName
2. 50,000 Premined.
3. 10,000 release schedule 10% every day started from " ex : tomorrow" for this address 0x

Note: web GUI with a button to claim the released tokens. (Gas fees will pay by the claimer's address).

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

1. In the constructor, mint 50,000 to the deployer (pre-mined) and 50,000 to the contract itself.
2. Create a view function to compute days since "birthday" to work out tokens released so far, 10k, 20k, 30k ... to max 50k.
3. Track claims to date and subtract from released. Any non-zero difference is claimable.
4. Create a withdraw function that allows an entitled user to withdraw the claimable tokens from the contract. Those are transferred from the contract to the user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing your inputs here. Sorry for reaching you out of the blue. I was wondering if you could assist me with this. I am kind of not finding any information anywhere else.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/swap-for-tokens-with-bot-protection-enabled-bpenabled
Thanks a ton in advance.